# What are the reasons an imported Webpack module would not end up in a chunk?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

We've got a fairly simple app/webpack setup which goes something like this:

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [...],
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      useBuiltIns: 'entry',
      corejs: '3'
    }]
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
import './polyfill';
import app from './app';
app();
```

**polyfill.js**

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
  entry: {
    bundle: [pathToIndexJs]
  }

  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What we end up with is two chunks, `bundle` and `vendors`. The strange part is that `whatwg-fetch` (and `core-js`) does not end up in a chunk. When I create a build and output a stats.json file and analyze it using [Webpack Analyze](http://webpack.github.io/analyse), I see the module in the list of modules (./node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js) but its *chunks* column is empty. I have verified that it is not ending up in either chunk/bundle by searching the bundle code.

This issue is fixed if I add the polyfill to the beginning of the `entry.bundle` array, but I am wondering why is it not being included in the bundle in the first place, since it is a normal app import? I would expect it to appear in the `vendors` bundle since it is a node_module.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `core-js` you don't have to add core-js anywhere.
All you have to do is install core-js, create a `.babelrc` file and place the following in it

```
{
 "presets": [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "debug": true,
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "corejs": 3
    }
   ]
  ]
}
```

Dubug parameter shows exactly what polyffils are added and to what.
Your code should look like this.

**index.js**

```
import app from './app';
app();
```

Webpack stays as it is

**UPDATE**

I forgot one more thing and the most important thing for it you can't see pollyfils.

**package.json**

```
"browserslist": [
 "last 2 version",
 ">1%",
 "not dead"
],
```

Of course, you can adjust the list of browsers you want to get polyffils -> [browserl](https://browserl.ist/)

**EDIT**
What is the difference between `"useBuiltIns": "usage"` vs `"useBuiltIns": "entry"`
`Entry` adds all polyfills and `Usage` only those that are needed for specific browsers.
Example file after compilation had `7KB` after using `Usage` 47KB and after changing to `Entry` up to 114KB! The difference is huge.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize it would affect my question, but we have a `babel.config.js` which includes the `preset-env` exactly as you have it shown (minus the debug option).

Comment: Remove it `import "core-js/stable"; import "whatwg-fetch";` Turn on debug
But I forgot one more thing and the most important thing for it you can't see pollyfils. If you don't have it, you won't get poliffils
In package.json add this entry `"browserslist": [ "last 2 version", "> 1%" "not dead"
   ]`
After this entry and launch in the console you will see the docs which is taken :)
And all polyffils should be included in the code. 

I did update the answer

Comment: Hmmm, I did as you suggested and realized that we were using `useBuiltIns: 'entry'`, which, [according to docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins) should replace our core-js import. Not sure why *that* wasn't happening. I changed it to "usage" per your answer and removed the core-js and whatwg-fetch line and everything was fine. Still though, `fetch` is undefined because core-js *doesn't* include a polyfill for it. But my question still remains. Why didn't Webpack include core-js and the fetch polyfill considering we imported them into index.js?

Comment: You are right my mistake core-js does not contain fetch polyfills. I checked in my project, I have, as I described, I do not import core-js and polyffils. Corejs does it for me. In the webpack analyzer I have core-js with all polyffils [webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-boilerplate)